# bash скрипт, цикл просить ввод переменной, до тех пор пока введена пустая строка

Tags: bash

Хочу чтобы пользователь в bash скрипте ввел переменную, и сделать проверку, чтобы если строка была пустая, скрипт все равно просил ввести эту переменную. А если переменная введена, продолжать скрипт дальше. Пытаюсь сделать обычным циклом `while`, но все равно после ввода любого значения цикл снова просит ввести переменную. Как правильно сделать проверку.

```
while [ $pass=='' ]
do
  read -p "Введите переменную: " pass
  echo $pass
done
```

Comment: Как минимум вы забыли поставить пробелы вокруг ==

Comment: `while [ -z $pass ]`

Comment: или `while [ "$pass" == "" ]`

Answer (score 0):

В данном контексте удобнее использовать `until` а не `while`:

```
until [[ $pass ]]
do
  read -p "Введите переменную: " pass
  echo $pass
done
```